# RWD default.phtml repetitive if-statements

Tags: rwd-theme, rwd

I'm studying Magento and have run into a strange phenomenon in the coding of the default.phtml file (path: site.com/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml). It looks like the if-statement on line 122:

```
<?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
```

is exactly the same as the if-statement on line 164:

```
<?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
```

Both are nested within the if-statement in the else statement on line 120 and I can't find a reason why these statements wouldn't cause both table data tags to be shown in the rendered document.

Anyone know what's going on here? Am I going crazy? Here's the full code for reference.

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     rwd_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
$_item = $this->getItem();
$isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
$canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM);
?>
<tr>
    <td class="product-cart-image">
        <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image">
        <?php endif;?>
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(180); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" />
        <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?>
            </a>
        <?php endif;?>

        <ul class="cart-links">
            <?php if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getConfigureUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Edit item parameters') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Edit') ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart() && $isVisibleProduct) : ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getMoveFromCartUrl($_item->getId()); ?>" class="link-wishlist use-ajax"><?php echo $this->__('Move to wishlist'); ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endif ?>
        </ul>
    </td>

    <td class="product-cart-info">

        <a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?>" class="btn-remove btn-remove2"><?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?></a>

        <h2 class="product-name">
        <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?></a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </h2>

        <div class="product-cart-sku">
            <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('SKU'); ?>:</span> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()); ?>
        </div>

        <?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                <dd<?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?> class="truncated"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
                <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
                <div class="truncated_full_value">
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                        <dd><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?></dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php if ($messages = $this->getMessages()): ?>
        <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
            <p class="item-msg <?php echo $message['type'] ?>">
                * <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?>
            </p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php $addInfoBlock = $this->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
        <?php if ($addInfoBlock): ?>
            <?php echo $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif;?>

    </td>

    <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
        <td class="a-center product-cart-price"<?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?> colspan="2"<?php endif; ?>>
            <span class="cart-price">
                <span class="cart-msrp-unit"><?php echo $this->__('See price before order confirmation.'); ?></span>
                <?php $helpLinkId = 'cart-msrp-help-' . $_item->getId(); ?>
                <a id="<?php echo $helpLinkId ?>" href="#" class="map-help-link"><?php echo $this->__("What's this?"); ?></a>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    Catalog.Map.addHelpLink($('<?php echo $helpLinkId ?>'), "<?php echo $this->__("What&#39;s this?") ?>");
                </script>

            </span>
        </td>
    <?php else: ?>

        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
        <td class="product-cart-price" data-rwd-label="<?php echo $this->__('Price'); ?>" data-rwd-tax-label="<?php echo $this->__('Excl. Tax'); ?>">

            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="cart-price">
            <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </span>

            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

                <div class="cart-tax-info" id="eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?><!-- inclusive price starts here -->
        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
        <td class="product-cart-price" data-rwd-label="<?php echo $this->__('Price'); ?>" data-rwd-tax-label="<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?>">
            <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getPriceInclTax($_item); ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="cart-price">
            <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </span>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

                <div class="cart-tax-info" id="unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <td class="product-cart-actions" data-rwd-label="<?php echo $this->__('Qty'); ?>">
        <input type="text" pattern="\d*" name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" />

        <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="update_qty" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update'); ?>" class="button btn-update"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update'); ?></span></span>
        </button>

        <ul class="cart-links">
            <?php if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getConfigureUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Edit item parameters') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Edit') ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
            <li>
                <?php if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getMoveFromCartUrl($_item->getId()); ?>" class="link-wishlist use-ajax"><?php echo $this->__('Move to wishlist'); ?></a>
                <?php endif ?>
            </li>
            <?php endif ?>
        </ul>

    </td>

    <!--Sub total starts here -->
    <?php if (($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()) && !$_item->getNoSubtotal()): ?>
    <td class="product-cart-total" data-rwd-label="<?php echo $this->__('Subtotal'); ?>">
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
            <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('esubtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="cart-price">
        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
                <span class="cart-msrp-subtotal">--</span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </span>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

            <div class="cart-tax-info" id="esubtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('esubtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                    <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()) && !$_item->getNoSubtotal()): ?>
    <td class="product-cart-total" data-rwd-label="<?php echo $this->__('Subtotal'); ?>">
        <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getSubtotalInclTax($_item); ?>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
            <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('subtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="cart-price">
        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
                <span class="cart-msrp-subtotal">--</span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getRowWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </span>


        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

            <div class="cart-tax-info" id="subtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('subtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                    <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getRowWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <td class="a-center product-cart-remove">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?>" class="btn-remove btn-remove2"><?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually they are two different statements. One of them is calling the 'tax' helper's **displayCartPriceExclTax** method while the other is calling the **displayCartPriceInclTax**. One of them is **Excl** - excluding and one of them is **Incl** including.